# pros and cons of high php session.sid_bits_per_character and session.sid_length?

Tags: php, security

As the title asks,

What are the pros and cons of high php session.sid_bits_per_character and session.sid_length?
The obvious pros are that the higher bits and length means even harder to brute force or overlaps, but is there much or any cons aside from the vague compatibility problem?

I ask this as that is as much information the manual provides.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function

I can imagine possible cons, but these are at most dumb guesses.

- longer length means bigger cookies and longer processing, also longer for RDBS id matching (with the unique, key column constraints? But as a key column, shouldn't matter right?)
- longer to generate? Maybe but probably by an impactable amount??
- Uses more resources for the longer length, but what about bit size does that use more resources? And is it even noticably more for the length and/or bit increase.

Is there any reason NOT to change these 2 settings to the following in the php.ini file?

```
sid_bits_per_character = 6
sid_length = 256
```

edit: added the possible con of using more resources

Comment: As always: it depends. The longer, and the more characters, the more secure. I don't think you will notice any speed impact. Also as cookies are always transmitted in the headers, that little more size won't really matter. If it IS about speed, you need to benchmark for YOUR system. You also can use memcached or redis as alternative storing the SID instead of the file system storage.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks for the comment. I don't have anything resembling a system yet, just a rdbms and xampp. Am I correct in assuming that using file system storage is the slowest for sid matching, rdbms key column next, and memcached/redis the fastest as they are straight key/val referencing? Or is memcached/redis pretty much equivalent with rdbms (mysql) table with a primary key column? But in general I am getting from you is that it doesn't matter and longer+more bits is better.

Comment: Also here it depends. A *NIX filesystem is phreaking fast and can be even faster than a in memory cache (because of handling connections). I would use one if you need to share a key/value store over multiple server instances and only change to optimize anything when you encounter any performance bottlenecks. As said, you need to measure for YOUR system.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Let me state some other conditions a) The only system I have is my PC and b) I'm currently using a RDBMS for the session storage and c) I am using phpsession. Other types of storages are  better/worse of course. But the question is NOT for my MY system, but for in general if there is any meaningful impact to speed/load/performance with higher SID length and bit size.

Comment: Then I would clearly say it will not make a big difference, when a RDBMS is the session manager. Just be aware of using "the right" indexes. You also can use in memory tables when using mySQL (but sessions are gone on server reboot). Again, there's no general correct way. But my thumb rule: always measure and optimize when needed.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thank you, I'll investigate "the right indexes" and "in memory tables" things. They seem interesting especially the in memory table for mySQL, as the answer says that since sids are ephemeral, losing a session table on reboot seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sids are ephemeral rather than permanent. So the number of them you need to store is proportional to the number of active users you have, not total users. That's good when you use an RDBMS for session storage: in large tables random primary keys are not very efficient but session tables -- with sids for primary keys -- aren't that large.

Ephemerality also means you can change sid format in the future, with the only operational cost being the cancellation of all active sessions when you switch. You can get away with that once in a great while if you announce scheduled downtime.

Longer sids are more secure. Adding six bits to a random sid makes it 64 times harder to guess. A 192-bit sid (32 bytes at six bits per byte) is just fine, and won't raise flags with people like payment-card industry infosec auditors. Longer is OK too, but 256 bytes is overkill. The extra cost, CPU, storage, and bandwidth, of a few-bytes-longer cookie value is too small to measure. You can save thousands of times more server and bandwidth resources by  doing things like compressing images more efficiently. Much bigger payoff than shaving bytes off sids.

Avoid using MD5 or SHA-1 hash algorithms. Use SHA-224 or something at least as secure. Auditors don't like the less secure ones. Using a better one saves you the hassle of explaining to the auditor how the worse ones are still ok for short-lived ephemeral values.

The session subsystem in php lets you switch from file-system session storage to RDBMS or cache-server storage when your site traffic grows enough that you need it : when you need multiple load-balanced  web server machines. You don't have to overengineer that part of your app from day one. Just do your session-variable development correctly and you're ready for the future.

Comment: So to break it down, because its ephemeral its impact to a RDBMS PK column is minimal if not negligible, but longer/random keys can be problematic if the row count gets large because it if not efficient. Otherwise, SID length/bit size performance cost is in general outside of its session storage system, IS negligible. Am I correct in this? Thank you! Also you bring up pw hash algorithms, but phpsession defaults to blowfish, I looked it up and it seems better than md5 and sha-1 at least, not sure about sha-224, is blowfish just as good or better than sha-224?

Comment: Yah, blowfish is fine.